# Can not list the bluetooth devices as a list

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to list the bluetooth devices as a list (NAME & ADDRESS) on my app but is not working.

This is my code :

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, Arrays.asList(pairedDevices.toString())));
```

It's saying that I have not permission to show the devices.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Well I see two errors in your code, if you want to show it as a "NAME & ADDRESS" as you said you have to make sure that you have this in your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Then to show what you want, you have to do this :

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
   s.add(bt.getName() + " : " + bt.getAddress());

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.list, s));
```

Then it should work.